# iOS 7 have a trouble about layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar

My app use `uitabbar` and `uinavigationbar`.but I encounter a problem in iOS7.1. if I switch page between one with `navigationbar` and one without `navigationbar`. the page have `scrollview` or `uitableview`,every time swith,self.view.frame or self.view.bounds is Correct，but `scrollview` or `uitableview`'s frame is Correct but bounds.y every time swith will change 20px.one up,one down.
i try to change `scrollview` or `uitableview's` `bounds.y` in view will `viewWillAppear`.
    `CGRect` `bounds` = `contentScrollView`.bounds;
bounds.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0);

contentScrollView.bounds = bounds;

but if i do it,ok,every time swith page is show right,but when i drag the `scrollview` or uitableview,the layout incorrect.

the demo has upload on github:https://github.com/KingCentLee/HSText
I hope someone can help me.the demo in iOS 7 later is normal. just iOS 7 swith page encounter the problem.and can tell the reason.Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your code. Try delete the code in `viewWillAppear`. I'am sorry, I don't have ios7 device. In my memory, it may cause by the system status bar which height is just 20px.   This is only a suggestion.  ps:I can't add a comment.